# pubnub display message "CAN'T SAVE DUMP" is it an error? How to silence it if not?

Tags: ios, pubnub

I keep on getting this message on the console log under XCODE. I try to keep the console clean and this bugs me (more than it should really ... :) )

```
CAN'T SAVE DUMP
```

i'm wondering if it's actually an error and if not how to silence it.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue saving the dump file to the device storage. Check to be sure you have enough free space on the device to write to, and also be sure you don't have any filesystem permissions issues. If the issue persists, contact us at support@pubnub.com and we'll dig deeper with you.

Comment: Thanks Geremy. Is the dump file critical to PUBNUB internals or can I disable this feature? I tried [PNLogger saveToDump:NO]; with no luck.

Comment: Nope, its not critical, only used for debugging purposes.